# White Black Cube

Tags: matrices, algorithms

Given a cube of dimension N*N*N made of unit cubic cell and color of each cell could be black or white.I want to find maximum size of subcube which has atleast K% of its cells as black.

I want to find the maximum size of this subcube and also the number of such subcubes with this size that follow the above mentioned condition.

Please help to provide an efficient algorithm.